# iOS 13 Closing App on Background: Audio Stream Issue

Tags: ios, swift, audio, background, audio-streaming

I'm stuck in playing audio on the background with Swift 5 and Xcode 11.

Enabling Background Mode and starting AVAudioSession no longer works and the app keeps closing after a few seconds when you leave the app.

First I get a entitlement warming, but the stream starts:

```
Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x2829830f0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Required client entitlement is missing"> {
userInfo = {
    RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x1050a9040; requestedReason: MediaPlayback; reason: MediaPlayback; flags: PreventTaskSuspend | PreventTaskThrottleDown | WantsForegroundResourcePriority>;
}
```

When after a few seconds on the background it closes:

```
[ProcessSuspension] Background task expired while holding WebKit ProcessAssertion (isMainThread? 1).
```

If I keep the app open the audio stops anyway:

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x10dfc8848 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```

Apple loves to change this every year. Anyone got this working on iOS 13 and Xcode 11/Swift 5 so far?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I just found out **this issue is affecting only audio played through WebViews**. I'm not sure if this is a bug on iOS 13 or if Apple is really cutting WebViews from multitasking. So I changed my app and the audio is now being played through the AVPlayer. Background audio works again.

Comment: Share your AVAudioSession related code snippet

Comment: Use AVPlayer for now. AVaudioPlayer isn't working for me either

Answer (score 0):

do you put code for resume play audio in you Appdelegate

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {


    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

addition make audio, airplay,and picture in picture on from your target capabilities

Comment: This doesn't stop audioPlayer from stopping in the background either, OP could use AVPlayer instead, my AVPlayerController keeps my music in the background while audioPlayer shuts down after few seconds.

Comment: @K4747Z How exactly did you fix the issue?

Comment: and why is this with `try`??? this is not android... or actually with tim cook it becomes android...